# Что это за язык программирования?

Tags: парсер

```
################################################################
    @auto[]

    ################################################################
    @data[]
    $bar_promo[^oSql-main.table{
        SELECT
            promo.url,
            promo_files.file_key,
            promo_files.file_ex,
            promo_files.file_width,
            promo_files.file_height
        FROM
            ${db-main}.promo
        LEFT JOIN promo_files ON promo.id = promo_files.parent_id
        WHERE
            section = 'bar' AND is_pub = '1'
        GROUP BY promo.id
        ORDER BY promo.n
    }]

    $bar_teasers[^table::sql{
        SELECT
            teasers.id,
            teasers.title_ru as title,
            teasers.text_ru as text,
            teasers.url_ru as url,
            teasers.file_ex_ru as file_ex,
            teasers.file_width_ru as file_width,
            teasers.file_height_ru as file_height
        FROM
            ${db-main}.teasers
        WHERE
            section = 'bar' AND is_pub = '1'
        ORDER BY teasers.n
    }]

    ################################################################
    @title[]
    $result[Спорт-бар]

    ################################################################
    @head_params[]
    <meta name="description" content="$mp.description" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="$mp.keywords" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/$path.css/mp.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/$path.js/slides.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        ^$(document).ready(function(){ 
            ^$('#slider').slides({ 
                container: 'slides', 
                preload: true, 
                play: 5000, 
                effect: 'fade', 
                crossfade: true 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>

    ################################################################
    @body[]
    ^if(def $bar_promo){
        <div class="promo"> 
            <div class="fix"> 
                <div id="slider" class="promo_container"> 
                    <div class="slides"> 
                        ^bar_promo.menu{
                            $block_banner_src[/i/promo/${bar_promo.file_key}.${bar_promo.file_ex}]
                            ^if(-f "$block_banner_src"){
                                ^try{
                                    $image[^image::measure[$block_banner_src]] 
                                    $block_url[${bar_promo.url}]
                                    ^if(def $block_url){
                                        $block_banner[<a href="$block_url">^image.html[$.border[0]]</a>] 
                                    }{
                                        $block_banner[^image.html[$.border[0]]] 
                                    }
                                    <div>$block_banner</div> 
                                }{
                                    $exception.handled(1)
                                    $image[]
                                    $block_url[]
                                    $block_banner[] 
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
    }

    <div class="fix"> 
        ^if(def $bar_teasers){
            <div class="teasers" style="padding:50px 0"> 
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> 
                    ^tableInColumns[$bar_teasers;3]{
                        <div class="block"> 
                            <h2> 
                                ^if(def $bar_teasers.url){
                                    <a href="$bar_teasers.url">$bar_teasers.title</a> 
                                }{
                                    $bar_teasers.title 
                                }
                            </h2> 
                            $block_banner_src[/i/teasers/${bar_teasers.id}_ru.${bar_teasers.file_ex}]
                            ^if(-f "$block_banner_src"){
                                ^try{
                                    ^switch[${bar_teasers.file_ex}]{
                                        ^case[jpg;jpeg;gif;png]{
                                            $image[^image::measure[$block_banner_src]] 
                                            $block_banner[^image.html[$.border[0]^if(^bar_teasers.file_width.int(0)){$.width[^bar_teasers.file_width.int(0)]}^if(^bar_teasers.file_height.int(0)){$.height[^bar_teasers.file_height.int(0)]}]] 
                                        }
                                        ^case[swf]{
                                            $file_width[^if(^bar_teasers.file_width.int(0)){$teasers.file_width}{100}]
                                            $file_height[^if(^bar_teasers.file_height.int(0)){$teasers.file_height}{100}]
                                            $block_banner[<object width="$file_width" height="$file_height" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="banner-${bar_teasers.id}" id="banner-${bar_teasers.id}"><param value="$block_banner_src" name="MOVIE"><param value="opaque" name="WMODE"><param value="true" name="PLAY"><param value="true" name="LOOP"><param value="high" name="QUALITY"><param value="false" name="MENU"><embed width="$file_width" height="$file_height" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" menu="false" quality="high" loop="true" play="true" wmode="opaque" src="$block_banner_src" name="banner-${bar_teasers.id}" id="banner-${bar_teasers.id}"></object>]
                                        }
                                    }
                                    <div class="i">$block_banner</div> 
                                }{$exception.handled(1)} 
                                $block_banner_src[]
                            }
                            <div class="t">^untaint[as-is]{$bar_teasers.text}</div> 
                        </div>              
                    }
                </table> 
            </div> 
        }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, это [парсер](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser)

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо. Оформите ответом.